# Jsonreststore posting and deleting

Tags: php, rest, dojo

I'm writing a PHP REST API using DOJO jsonreststore, I know many are already out there but it's mainly to get a good understanding of the concept. To check the results I connected the store to a datagrid and everything except for two things are working.

If I delete an item from the store it dissapears in the datagrid but if I look in firebug in the store._index the deleted items still remains. This might be because that view isn't updated?

Second is when I post a new item and the backend returns the newly created item + the generated id. The datagrid is updated with a new row only without my newly generated id. If I look in firebug in the store._index I see an item with my newly created ID as I expected but there still remains an item with a client side generated ID. The datagrid is showing the object without the id generated server side.

But stuck here, any thoughts?

Below I posted some code:

Adding item:

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId("addLocation"), "onClick", function() { 
    var Location = locationStore.getConstructor();                  
    var location = new Location();

    location.name = "TESTLOC"
    location.description = "TESTDESC"
    location.company = "1"
    location.companyname = "TEST"

    locationStore.save();                   
});

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $putvars = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));       
    $location = new Location();

    $location->setCompany($putvars->company);
    $location->setCompanyName($putvars->companyname);
    $location->setDescription($putvars->description);
    $location->setId(14);
    $location->setName($putvars->name);

    header("HTTP/1.0 201 Created", true, 201);
    header("Location: http://localhost/resttest/location/" . 14);
    echo $location->toJSON();
}
```

Deleting item:

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId("deleteLocation"), "onClick", function() { 
    var location = locationGrid.getItem(0);

    locationStore.deleteItem(location);
    locationStore.save();
});

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "DELETE") {
    $uri = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);        
    $locationId = $uri[count($uri)-1];

    header("HTTP/1.0 204 OK", true, 204);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `remove(id)` and `add(object, options)` instead. The JsonRest store follows `CRUD` pattern which is the short for **C** reate **R** ead **U** pdate **D** elete. However, functions is mapped diferently, `add()`, `get()`, `delete()` (yay) and `put()` (which has overwrite flag).

Try a bit of different approach.

#### delete

```
var id = getIdentity(locationGrid.getItem(0))
locationStore.delete(id);
```

#### add

```
var location = {
 name = "TESTLOC",
 description = "TESTDESC",
 company = "1",
 companyname = "TEST"
}
locationStore.add(location).then(
     function(response) {
     }
});
```

As i recall, a generic ID is created if not supplied clientside.. Consider calculating the uniq ID as a sequential primary and simply add 1 to highest known identity.

Otherwise you would have to read the response from `add` operation (in the Deferred callback) and set the ID of the newly created item.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply! If I look at the DOJO API docs for the rest store and superclass servicestore I don't see the functions you mention (add, get, delete and put). Nevertheless I tried them and I also get an error indicating those functions don't exist. Furthermore in different online resources it is stated that if an item is created or updated you can return that specific item from your service in order to make back end enrichment possible in case of ID generation since I don't want my client(s) to create an id for me, so that's kinda confusing. What version of DOJO do you use? I'm at 1.8

Comment: the api reference is not very well structured and in fact i have never found what i was looking for there.. make a custom of checking source files if in doubt (the commented non-squished version ofc). The is, if the docs is of no help, find **dojo/store/JsonRest** here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store/JsonRest.html

Comment: Just found out the difference between our stores :) I was still using the (in 1.8 deprecated) dojox.data.JsonRestStore and you're correct in using the dojo.store.JsonRest, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Made a typo :s the reststore is now behaving as expected.

Nevertheless still strange that the store maintains local copies of items that have been deleted/created perhaps for reverting. Anyway it is working for me so I guess case closed.